# Why doesn't a TensorFlow cubic model work when an equivalent quadratic model works?

Tags: python-3.x, intellij-idea, tensorflow

In this sample code (mostly like the example code for a linear regression [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started)), TensorFlow is supposed to find `a, b, c, and d` values for given points making up a cubic. In this case, it should be `0x^3 + 0x^2 + 1x + 0`, but instead gets steadily larger and larger until it hits `nan`.

The strange thing is that the same code with a modification to the line:

`model = a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d`
to

`model = a * x * x + b * x + c`
will give correct output (for a quadratic instead of cubic, of course). What's the issue?

**Code here:**

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Don't remove this, I need it to mitigate tf build warnings
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# Model parameters
a = tf.Variable([1.], tf.float64)
b = tf.Variable([1.], tf.float64)
c = tf.Variable([1.], tf.float64)
d = tf.Variable([1.], tf.float64)
# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
model = a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
# Loss
squared_deltas = tf.square(model-y)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)
# Optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
# Training Data
x_train = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
y_train = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
# Training Loop
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(1000):
    curr_a, curr_b, curr_c, curr_d = sess.run([a, b, c, d], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
    print("Formula: %s x^3 + %s x^2 + %s x + %s" % (curr_a, curr_b, curr_c, curr_d))
    sess.run([train], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
# Evaluate Training Accuracy
curr_a, curr_b, curr_c, curr_d = sess.run([a, b, c, d], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
print("Formula: %s x^3 + %s x^2 + %s x + %s" % (np.round(curr_a), np.round(curr_b), np.round(curr_c), np.round(curr_d)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## All about the gradient

Now with a larger possible loss function your gradient of 0.01 is too large which makes corrections become unstable.

Also, to accomidate a smaller gradient you'll need more steps.  Here is the working code

## Code

```
    import os
    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np

    # Don't remove this, I need it to mitigate tf build warnings
    os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

    # Model parameters
    a = tf.Variable([1.], tf.float64)
    b = tf.Variable([1.], tf.float64)
    c = tf.Variable([1.], tf.float64)
    d = tf.Variable([1.], tf.float64)
    # Model input and output
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    model = a * x * x * x + b * x * x + c * x + d
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    # Loss
    squared_deltas = tf.square(model-y)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(squared_deltas)
    # Optimizer
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
    # Training Data
    x_train = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
    y_train = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
    # Training Loop
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(10000):
        curr_a, curr_b, curr_c, curr_d = sess.run([a, b, c, d], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
        if i % 100 == 0 :
            print("Formula: %s x^3 + %s x^2 + %s x + %s" % (curr_a, curr_b, curr_c, curr_d))
        sess.run([train], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
    # Evaluate Training Accuracy
    curr_a, curr_b, curr_c, curr_d = sess.run([a, b, c, d], {x: x_train, y: y_train})
    print("Formula: %s x^3 + %s x^2 + %s x + %s" % (np.round(curr_a), np.round(curr_b), np.round(curr_c), np.round(curr_d)))
```

## Output

```
...
Formula: [  3.50048867e-06] x^3 + [  8.49209730e-11] x^2 + [ 0.99998665] x + [  7.22413340e-13]
Formula: [  3.49762831e-06] x^3 + [  8.49209730e-11] x^2 + [ 0.99998665] x + [  5.92354182e-13]
Formula: [  3.50239748e-06] x^3 + [  8.49209730e-11] x^2 + [ 0.99998665] x + [  4.85032262e-13]
Formula: [ 0.] x^3 + [ 0.] x^2 + [ 1.] x + [ 0.]
```

## Final comments (updated)

This problem really comes from the lines :

```
# Loss
squared_deltas = tf.square(model-y)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(squared_deltas)
```

The gradient of **loss** can become *HUGE*er when we add that x^3 term.

Another solution would be to change the loss function to use tf.reduce_mean.  I didn't see this the first time I looked at the code.

```
# Loss
squared_deltas = tf.square(model-y)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(squared_deltas)
# Optimizer
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
```

If you use *tf.reduce_mean* your workflow will not have to be re-adjusted each time you change your batch size or number of parameters.  This is *now* my preferred solution.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. Do you mind clarifying why adding outputs to a bounded variable should help with reducing loss? Also, what *is* the point of squaring the deltas?

Comment: Hi @EvanWeissburg - if this solves your problem (which it does) please accept it as the correct answer.  As for squaring the deltas, that is one way of measuring *how incorrect* the answer is.  It will give *much* larger corrections for error that is more wrong ... by the square no-less.  If you are familiar with RMS (root mean square) error, this is the mean square part of it.

Comment: For example, if you have 4 training examples and your abs delta error per training example is [ 0 , 0 , 0 , 10 ], it basically means you are just missing that one data point.  Instead if your abs delta error is [ 3 , 3 , 3 , 3 ] then your function probably isn't overfit.  The sum of squares of [0,0,0,10] is 100, where as the sum of squares of [3,3,3,3] is 37.  As you can see, using sum of squares gives an indication that [3,3,3,3] is better than [0,0,0,10].

Comment: That makes sense. Why does adding outputs to an unbounded variable help with loss refuction as in your Final Comments?

Comment: hey, I updated the solution to my preferred solution.  I just noticed now that you were using *tf.reduce_sum*.  After dealing with variable batch sizes and variable feature sizes on different projects I've found that *tf.reduce_mean* handles these cases very well because of obvious. (because you don't want your loss to be a function of the *number* of features)